# Removing Firmware Lock

Tags: startup, recovery, firmware

Back when I bought my me and my girlfriend a mac I also set up a firmware password and I now want to remove it from hers.

I'm not sure I remember it correctly though. If it boots into recovery and asks me for the firmware password, can I still reboot normally in case I get the firmware password wrong? Or will I look myself out requiring a (currently not possible) trip to an Apple Store?

Comment: The password issue you have with your own computer is related to the firmware password as well?

Comment: Yes, it is.

Basically, my question is: Can I attempt to access the recovery mode to remove the Firmware password without it locking me out if I end up getting it wrong?